# Is it possible to create a "Meta-Forum" view when using organic groups?

Tags: views, organic-groups, nodes

We are using Drupal 6.x with organic groups. The groups have very different users and permission sets, and each group has a forum.

I was wondering if it is possible to have a kind of "Meta-Forum" view, i.e. one view in which all of the different Forums the user has access rights to are displayed, organized by group.

I have had a look at configuring a View for this, and while I am able to get things like a list of the most recent forum entries in all the subscribed groups, I was not able to get a "forum type" view where I have the groups on the highest level, then the individual forums and posts below this.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to build such of "forum" using Views. If you are using Organic Group Access, the view will be automatically filtered and only the content accessible to the user will be displayed.

Note that the [OG Forum](http://drupal.org/project/og_forum) module has been abandoned due to security issues and should not be used. Depending on your requirements, it might be easier to simply use standard Views for the group forums (after all, a forum is nothing more then a View of taxonomy terms attached to a View of nodes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I must admit that my Drupal knowledge is still not very good... Is there any pointer to how a View should be configured as a staring point?

Comment: I have updated the original question to reflect what I found out about Views and what I tried.